# Which types of eclipses are there?

Tags: aphorism

During Aphorism several different types of eclipses happen, which to the characters seems to be the most common thing in the world.

Thanks to that explanation of the types of eclipses seems to lack somewhat.

So which types of eclipses exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In chapter 73 there was a translator reminding readers that there was a page in chapter 44, speaking in detail about the different types of eclipses/blights. Reading this chapter again

- Normal Types

*Banquet* for example. They are simple blights, which can be resolved by a single student. These blights are also canceled if it rains.

- Fixed Types

*Obon* for example. They only occur on special days, such as [Obon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bon_Festival) or the first day of school. These blights are also canceled if it rains.

- Separation Types

*Dragon* for example. Separation type events occur only when the student body becomes divisible by 3. If a group fails to complete the given task, they perish. These blights are also canceled if it rains.

- Special Types

*Kingdom* for example. Special types last several days, and get stronger each day. It won't stop till it's completed, or the student body is completely obliterated. This event won't be affected by rain.